# How to deploy a Flask application in IIS 8 (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: python, iis, flask, iis-8

How do I deploy a Flask application in IIS 8 (Windows Server 2012)? There are many partial explanations around, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

*Just in case. I wouldn't do anything of this in production for complex and important app.*

I'd go for reverse proxy + gunicorn. That's what I do most of the times nowadays but with nginx and on linux machines. The problem here is that gunicorn doesn't support windows for now ([but support is planned](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues?milestone=7&state=open)). Now you have an option to run your Flask app with gunicorn in Cygwin.

The other way around would be to try this https://serverfault.com/questions/366348/how-to-set-up-django-with-iis-8 but instead of Django related stuff and especialy

```
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler as DjangoHandler
```

you need your Flask paths and env variables and

```
from yourapplication import app as FlaskHandler
```

**NB**: instead of gunicorn you can try other launchers listed [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/wsgi-standalone/). May be there's more luck with Twisted or Tornado on Windows

**Update: Gunicorn in Cygwin**

I'm on Window 7 64bit with Cygwin 1.7.5 32bit. Python version 2.6.8.

I had some issues running Flask with Cygwin 64bit and Python 2.7 although gunicorn seemed to work ok.

You can get Cygwin [here](http://cygwin.com/install.html).

Packages I've installed:

- nano
- python 2.6.8
- curl

Then I installed pip with:

```
$ curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | python
$ easy_install pip
```

And then flask and gunicorn:

```
$ pip install flask gunicorn
```

I've made simple `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And run it with gunicorn:

```
$ gunicorn app:app
2013-11-27 16:21:53 [8836] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2013-11-27 16:21:53 [8836] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (8836)
2013-11-27 16:21:53 [8836] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-11-27 16:21:53 [6140] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6140
```

After that you'll need to make your gunicorn app to run like [windows service](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Cygrunsrv). But that part I haven't done for a long time so memories are shaded:)

**NB**: I've found another option https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnWindows if you are ready to try

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy to try gunicorn if you can explain how to to get it working on Windows. Otherwise, could you please provide some more detail on how to set up one of the other launchers and how to integrate it with IIS?

Answer (score 0):

I had more success with this method using FastCGI: http://codesmartinc.com/2013/04/12/running-django-in-iis7iis8/

Just use `(yourModule).app` instead of `django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()` for the `WSGI_Handler` variable.